# showing and hiding password for Imagebutton inside edittext

Tags: java, android

I added Image inside edit text for showing and hiding password..how to perform 
on click operation for showing and hiding password for that image on inside editText

below is mycode

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_icon"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/routerPassWd"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:hint="Enter Passwd"/>
```

Comment: check this demo: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/518641/Show-hide-password-in-a-edit-text-view-password-ty. and post your code

Comment: You should include the code so that people can assist. It also shows some effort being expended.

Comment: you understand my question..I am  asking if place Image button inside edittext for that thing how to perform on click operation

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
            // show password
            etPassword.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());

            // hide password
            etPassword.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance()



     // to show try this another way


      editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL);



     // to hide

      editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: have u Try This

etPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL);

Comment: I Tried..problem is..once I type password in editText..then i click on button..it will show password..but if again click it wont hide password..it will stop..

Comment: editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                            InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

Comment: @pruthvivreddy Welcome Bro if my Answer Help You Please Accept My Answer

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding you have added an Image in the EditText and upon that image's click you want to show/hide the text transformation. If is that so then you have to create a custom EditText that will provide you the click for that image. Following is the code for an EditText which provides you the click listener for the image. You can use that in your code and toggle the transformation accordingly.

```
public class DrawableEditText extends EditText {
private Drawable left;
private Drawable top;
private Drawable right;
private Drawable bottom;
private int actionX;
private int actionY;
private DrawableClickListener listener;

public DrawableEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public DrawableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public DrawableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public void setCompoundDrawables(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom) {
    this.left = left;
    this.top = top;
    this.right = right;
    this.bottom = bottom;
    super.setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Rect bounds;
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        actionX = (int) event.getX();
        actionY = (int) event.getY();
        if (bottom != null && bottom.getBounds().contains(actionX, actionY)) {
            listener.onClick(this, DrawableClickListener.Position.BOTTOM);
        } else if (top != null && top.getBounds().contains(actionX, actionY)) {
            listener.onClick(this, DrawableClickListener.Position.TOP);
        } else if (left != null) {
            bounds = null;
            bounds = left.getBounds();
            int x, y;
            int extraTapArea = (int) (13 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5);
            x = actionX;
            y = actionY;
            if (!bounds.contains(actionX, actionY)) {
                x = (int) (actionX - extraTapArea);
                y = (int) (actionY - extraTapArea);
                if (x <= 0)
                    x = actionX;
                if (y <= 0)
                    y = actionY;
                if (x < y) {
                    y = x;
                }
            }
            if (bounds.contains(x, y) && listener != null) {
                listener.onClick(this, DrawableClickListener.Position.LEFT);
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                return false;
            }
        } else if (right != null) {
            bounds = null;
            bounds = right.getBounds();
            int x, y;
            int extraTapArea = 13;
            x = (int) (actionX + extraTapArea);
            y = (int) (actionY - extraTapArea);
            x = getWidth() - x;
            if (x <= 0) {
                x += extraTapArea;
            }
            if (y <= 0)
                y = actionY;
            if (bounds.contains(x, y) && listener != null) {
                listener.onClick(this, DrawableClickListener.Position.RIGHT);
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void setOnDrawableClickListener(DrawableClickListener l) {
    listener = l;
}

public static interface DrawableClickListener {

    public static enum Position {
        LEFT, TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM
    }

    void onClick(View v, Position position);
}
}
```

Just replace your EditText with this in you XML & place that image inside

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_icon"
```

Inside you Java file use:

```
DrawableEditText editText = (DrawableEditText) findViewById(R.id.<your id>);
editText.setOnDrawableClickListener(new DrawableClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v, Position position) {
        switch (position) {
            case RIGHT:
                //TODO code to switch between transformation
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this will help you